# How to check if a query with sql functions like max, count e.t.c. returns NULL?

Tags: mysql, sql, null, max

How can i check if a query with sql functions like max() returns NULL ?
Here is my code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(priority) FROM categories") or die('sel_pri:'.mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
            $max_pri = mysql_result($query, 0) or die('priority:'.mysql_error());
    else
        $max_pri = 0;
```

My categories table is epmty, so `mysql_num_rows()` will return 1, because this query will return 1 row with NULL value. The code above "dies"!
Also i have tryed:

```
if(empty($query))   
if(isset($query))
if(is_null($query))
```

But none of the above are working either.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you can as well supply the default value in SQL using `coalesce`, which returns the first non-null of it's arguments:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(priority), 0) FROM categories
```

Comment: Thanks!! `coalese` returns 0 if the table is empty, but `mysql_result()` still dies. I tryed insted mysql_fetch_array($query) wiht coalese, and with some modifications is working properly. Here is my code: `$query = mysql_query("SELECT COALESCE(MAX(priority), 0) AS max FROM categories WHERE parent_id=0") or die('sel_pri:'.mysql_error());
 $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
 $max_pri = $result['max'];`

Comment: @ioaniatr  The reason that `$max_pri = mysql_result($query, 0) OR die(...)` _dies_ is that 0 and "" is equal to `FALSE` so when either of these is returned, the statement after `OR` will be executed as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem I solved it with the following...

if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0)
{

if(!empty($query))
   {

```
       $max_pri = mysql_result($query, 0);

  } else

  {

       $max_pri = 0;

   }
```

}

Comment: In my example you mean: `$resultSet = mysql_result($query, 0);` or `$resultSet = $query` ? Because the first will die also and the second is not wotking...

Comment: Well, after a few tests i found out that all i need is `if(($query->num_rows)>0){ //mysql_result($query) }` It seems that the value is empty and it returns 0, although the rows are 1. The  `!empty($query)` is always NOT empty. Thanks

Comment: I run it again with rows in the table and `if(($query->num_rows)>0)` is always 0 (false). Actually `$max_pri` is 0 and all the fields priority in the table have the value 1 (my default value), Any idea why?

Comment: May be you are writing false (0) where as default value is true (1).. Change the $max_pri to any other number like 2 or 3.. it should solve your problem.

Comment: No, still the same, i changed my default value of the priority field in the table to 2 and still not working. `if(($query->num_rows)>0)` is always false, `if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)` is always > 0, and `if(!empty($query)) ` is always NOT empty (because $query is resource).

Comment: The problem with `mysql_num_rows($query)` seems to be when the table is empty. One solution would be to change the query to: `$rows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT priority FROM categories")); 
        if($rows > 0) 
        $max_pri = mysql_result("SELECT MAX(priority) FROM categories", 0) or die('priority:'.mysql_error());
    else
        $max_pri = 0; ` but is there any other way more simple?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the IFNULL function, its sounds more relevant.

```
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(priority),0) FROM categories
```